# nservicebus sendlocal headers not set

Tags: header, nservicebus

I'm sending messages in NServiceBus using both Send() and SendLocal(). For each of them I need to store some info in the headers. It appears that a message sends with SendLocal does not contain the headers (I can't reproduce it on my local dev environment but I can see it occurring in production with QueueExplorer). Could someone please confirm that headers are not sent with SendLocal() and suggest a workaround I can use or documentation I can read about that? thanks

Comment: Which version of NServiceBus are you using? The thing is, SendLocal calls through to Send so this sounds weird. Are you doing anything unusual with your configuration or initialization code?

Comment: Are you talkin about all headers missing or just the ones that you set your self?